# WCF REST WebServiceHostFactory using linq to sql

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, rest

I'm trying to implement a REST service using WCF which will take the parameters P1, P2, P3, P4 and pass them to a stored procedure which will perform a query and return the results.

I have this code in C# for the service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Data;

namespace RestServicePublishing
{
  [System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
  [ServiceContract]
  public class RestService
  {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public List<Simulated_service_State> GetState(decimal P1, decimal P2, decimal P3,  decimal P4)
    {
       using (ServiceDataContext db = new ServiceDataContext())
       {
           List<Simulated_service_State> states = 
              db.GetStateByLongLat(P1, P2, P3, P4).ToList();
           db.SubmitChanges();
           return states;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

`Simulated_Service_State` is a temp table to which I'm storing results from the stored procedure call. When I call the web service through browser I get the following error:

> Request Error
>
> The server encountered an error
>   processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.'. See
>   server logs for more details. The
>   exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   RestServicePublishing.ServiceDataContext..ctor()
>   in
>   C:....\RestServicePublishing\Service.designer.cs:line
>   39 at
>   RestServicePublishing.RestService.GetState(Decimal
>   P1, Decimal P2, Decimal P3, Decimal
>   P4) in
>   C:....\RestServicePublishing\RestService.svc.cs:line
>   42 at SyncInvokeGetState(Object ,
>   Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&
>   outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

!!!

The URL which I call is the following:

```
http://localhost/RestServicePublishing/RestService.svc/GetState?P1=14&P2=13&P3=22&P4=55
```

Can anybody help me to understand how to work with stored procedures and REST WCF service? How to return values from the temp table to the client?

**Update**

I was unable to post all this data into the comments section so I'm posting it here.
This is the code I'm using now, but it's giving me the 0 as result which means that my query doesn't pick anything from the table:

```
public class RestService
{        
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string GetState(decimal P1, decimal P2, decimal P3, decimal P4)
    {
        IList<Simulated_service_State> query = new List<Simulated_service_State>();
        IList<string> Mac = new List<string>();
        int j;
        int jj;

        using (ServiceDataContext db = new ServiceDataContext())
        {
            query = db.GetStateByLongLat1(P1, P2, P3, P4).ToList();
            db.SubmitChanges();
            var query2 = from Simulated_service_State state in db.Simulated_service_States
                         select state.MAC;
            Mac = query2.ToList();
            jj = Mac.Count;
            j = query.Count;
        }
        return j.ToString() + "," + jj.ToString();
    }
}
```

If I use this code (not a stored procedure) I'm getting the result from the table so I assume that the linq to sql works fine (ServiceDataContext):

```
public class RestService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string GetState(decimal P1, decimal P2, decimal P3, decimal P4)
    {
        IList<Simulated_service_State> query = new List<Simulated_service_State>();
        IList<string> Mac = new List<string>();
        int j;
        int jj;
        using (ServiceDataContext db = new ServiceDataContext())
        {
            var query3 = from SimulatedNode node in db.SimulatedNodes
                        select node.MAC;
            Mac = query3.ToList();
            j = (Mac.Count);
        }
        return j.ToString();
```

The result I get is 4 which represents the number of entries in the list.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Well can you debug into the `GetState` method and see **what** is NULL??

Comment: I am assuming that your `ServiceDataContext` cannot be created for some reason (not sure what that reason would be) - that's what the error message seems to point at...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't step into the code with debugger. I've setup the web.config file based on instructions from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157687.aspx  but I still can't debug the code. Any idea on how to step into the code?

Comment: btw: the same code (query by using linq-to-sql sproc) works when I set up the WCF SOAP service. But I'd need to setup the REST this time.

Comment: @Mark: you should be able to just run your WCF service by pressing F5 in Visual Studio, and then make a request to your service by typing in the URL into a browser. You should be able to have a breakpoint in your code (the method that gets called) and just be taken there when you make that request from the browser...

Comment: I know I should but I get this error: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL". I've searched the net and couldn't find the proper answer on how to resolve that issue.

Comment: Does anyone maybe could post some example of WCF REST service which uses linq to sql stored procedure? This might help me to get through this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up doing the query with stored procedure, so I used the standard sql query function which works and is providing results. Here is the final code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Data;

namespace RestServicePublishing
{
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =     AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
[ServiceContract]

public class RestService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet (ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<Last_status_by_LongLat> GetState(decimal P1, decimal P2, decimal P3, decimal P4)
    {
        List<Last_status_by_LongLat> Mac = new List<Last_status_by_LongLat>();

        using (ServiceDataContext db = new ServiceDataContext())
        {
            var query = from view node in db.views
                         where table.param > P1 && table.param2 < P2 && table.param2 > P3 && table.param < P4
                         select table;
            Mac = query.ToList();


        }
        return Mac;

    }
}
}
```

I'm passing the P1 - P4 parameters to the "where" statement of the sql call and I then pass the variable query to the "List Mac " which represents the SQL view as linq to sql.  At the end I'm returing the list content to the GetState WebGet call.

Comment: If anyone has the solution which works with stored procedure please share it. The coding with stored procedure is much simpler and cleaner and the data retrieval logic is done on the SQL server side (my personal opinion and personal preference).

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking GetStateByLongLat() is returning null. Then the ToList() would throw the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error.

Comment: I've tested this sproc in a SOAP based service and it's returning the results there. Also I've tested it as a console based client app (without exposing the results via web service) and it's working fine. What I suspect is that results from the GetStateByLongLat() doesn't pass the results to the List properly. But this is just a wild guess as I can't step into the code to see what exactly is happening there.

Comment: Old style debugging: do things explicitly: put result in a variable, check for null, iterate over it and add it to a new list, return list

Comment: I'm not getting the error anymore (I assume it was related to linq to sql authentication issue). This is the current code I'm using, but it's returing 0 as value.